# How to group Qt Test cmake targets in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, cmake, qt-creator

**My project structure looks like this**

```
 - application
   - main.cpp
   - something.h
   - something.cpp
   - something_else.h
 - unit_tests
   - test_something.cpp
   - test_something_else.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

Until now i was using Catch2 for testing, and i had 2 nice projects, one for the app, one for the tests. But now also some signal and slot based classes need to be tested, and that is much easier with Qt Test. So I'm switching to that.

**My CMakeFile looks like this:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(application_name LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Test)
enable_testing(true)
add_executable(application_name application/main.cpp application/something.h ...)
target_link_libraries(application_name PRIVATE Qt::Core)

enable_testing(true)

add_executable(test_something unittests/test_something.cpp)
add_test(NAME test_something COMMAND test_something)
target_link_libraries(test_something PUBLIC Qt::Test)

add_executable(test_something_else unittests/test_something_else.cpp)
add_test(NAME test_something_else COMMAND test_something_else)
target_link_libraries(test_something_else PUBLIC Qt::Test)
```

This works, i can run the tests form QtCreator, in the test pane or manually via the Build->Run.

**What bothers me, are the following:**

1. Every single unit test shows up in the project view as a separate project with one file.
2. The run configuration editor also shows every single test.

My actual project has several non-qt-test targets, and so the additional targets are cluttering up these two panes.

I would like to group the tests in the project view and ideally in the run configuration view. Is this possible?
For me it would be ideal to put all tests into one project, but this doesn't seem to be the canonical way for Qt Tests. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Did you try creating only a single test executable using all the test source files?

Comment: I overlooked you mentioning you tried putting them into one project, I assume you mean the same thing I meant. Using gtest, this is the canonical way, I don't know about Qt Test. Just for organizing this in the project pane, you could look into the cmake FOLDER property, if QtCreator supports that.

Comment: ye, qt test is really not designed for that: There is a macro that creates the main() function for a specified test class. I don't see a way on how to make qt-tests for several classes at once (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html). I found this about the FOLDER property in qt creator: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-5-cmake-projects-update. I tested it, and I can remove the unnecessary run entries, but the project view remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make a subdirectory, in it, create a new CMakeLists.txt and put all tests there. finally include that in the main project with add_subdirectory.

I moved away from qt unit tests in the meanwhile as i discovered, that it's possible to test signals and slots in catch2. but I saw that the above solution works.